# Problems with permissions with regards to importrange in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, importrange

I have an automated procedure, where a script every morning is searching for my mail inbox. Hereafter an excel attachment is download to my drive and converted to a Google sheet.

Now I have the other document, where I import data from the downloaded file from Gmail. However, every time I use `importrange` I need to grant it permission because I am always operating with a newly downloaded file.

I don't want to grant permission every day. Do you know how to solve this? Can I somehow say, that whenever I am the owner of any documents I don't need to give the individual document permission when I share data between them?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I somehow say, that whenever I am the owner of any documents I don't need to give the individual document permission when I share data between them?

There is no way to do this. Send your feedback to Google by using [Google Feedback](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback).

The above because the Google Sheets UI, the Sheets API and Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service haven't a way to do this.